# Canvas height changed by EaselJS. How to avoid this?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs, easeljs

I'm using Easel JS to develop Canvas based Solitaire game.

**TODO:** Set height for canvas and draw all elements inside of that.

**Issue:** EaselJS change the canvas height automatically.

**References:**

[image: Screenshot showing height of canvas in the browser]

[image: Height I've set for canvas in code.]

**How I set the height:**

```
      var gameBoard = document.getElementById("board");

  gameBoard.style.height = window.innerHeight+"px";
  gameBoard.height = gameBoard.offsetHeight;
  gameBoard.style.height = "auto";
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your goals are, it's hard to tell what the problem is exactly... but setting the CSS "canvas.style.height" property to "auto" seems to be the problem. The width and height properties (not CSS) are still what you set them to originally (1300 x 501).

Remove this line and you will be left with a canvas that is the size of the window when the page is loaded.

```
gameBoard.style.height = "auto";
```

If you want your canvas to have as many pixels as there are in the window, you will need to listen for the "resize" event and apply the values back to your canvas.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
});
```

Comment: Further to this, note that EaselJS never sets the size of your canvas, with the one exception being when you export from Flash/Animate CC -- the generated HTML has the FLA stage size. I would only recommend scaling using CSS if you understand what it will do, since it scales pixels, instead of changing dimensions. @inverse' suggestion setting the width/height on the canvas directly is more desirable.